# SKShapeNode Circle not appearing circular

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on an app where there should be a red circle on the screen. At first when I tested with only one scene, the circle appeared circular just fine. However, I have added in another scene and now the circle appears like this:
[image]

The circle appears to be much longer in the x direction. 
Here is the code I use to make the circle (All of this in an skscene):

```
    let ball = Ball(circleOfRadius: 500)//ball is a subclass of SKShapeNode
    ball.setScale((self.frame.height / 6) / 1000)            
    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 4, self.frame.height / 2)
    ball.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    ball.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.addChild(ball)
```

Here is the code I use to transition to the scene with the ball (A different skscene):

```
func transitionToGame(){
    let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0)
    let gameOverScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
}
```

Any ideas on why the ball would no longer appear as a circle? I a worried this is also going to throw off other nodes I attempt to add, and possible means the coordinate system is incorrect. I am happy to hear any ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"All of this in an skview" are you sure you aren't doing that in a SKScene?

If the ball is indeed getting added directly to the scene I would look at the scene.scaleMode in your View Controller. Most of the time people set it to `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill` but when you create a new scene you aren't setting the scaleMode. This might be as easy as making sure both scenes have the same scaleMode.

I am guessing this will fix your issue.

```
func transitionToGame(){
    let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0)
    let gameOverScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    gameOverScene.scaleMode = scene.scaleMode
    self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yes I meant to write SKScene, don't know why I wrote SKView. Thanks this works perfectly!